# Selectively exclude packages from CDI scanning

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi, weld

How can I exclude some or all packages from CDI scanning in Glassfish 4 with Java EE 7 technology stack?

I tried the mechanism described in the [Weld documents](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/configure.html#d0e5767), but it seems not working on Glassfish 4.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why it's not working, but try using [`@Vetoed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Vetoed.html) instead of a weld specific `xsd` in `beans.xml` as `@Vetoed` will be more portable since it's implementation independent. It should work since it's marked with `@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PACKAGE})`.